Flutter - Handling WebView back press in PopScope's onPopInvokedWithResult method
I am using the following version of Flutter:
Flutter 3.24.4
Dart 3.5.4

I am using the PopScope for WebView. How I can implement the WebView backpress in onPopInvokedWithResult method?
I recently migrated from WillPopScope to PopScope and was using the onWillPop with the following function:
  Future<bool> goBack() async {
    if(await webViewController.canGoBack()){
      webViewController.goBack();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }


EDIT: After OP asked me to edit my answer to include extra info.
EDIT2: SystemNavigator closes the app. So if you want to close the app, do this. For more, check the documentation.
Inside onPopInvokedWithResult you should do:
if (didPop) return;

final shouldPop = await webViewController.canGoBack();

if (shouldPop) {
   webViewController.goBack();
}

/// If your code arrives here, it means that shouldPop is false,
/// that means you press back, there is no history in the navigation 
/// stack, so we pop the webview screen and return to the WebView caller.
SystemNavigator.pop();

Check this from Flutter's documentation. The example is different, but the logic is similar.

Thanks for the answer. It's working for the browser but when there is no go back in the browser the back press doesn't work to close the app. Can you please edit the answer?

Thanks for the edits. My app is only a WebView app, after your edits, it only closes the WebView but the app remains open and shows the black screen. My intention is to close the app normally when there are no more go-backs in the WebView.
